# Copy SharePoint SPListItem while preventing new workflows or modifications

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm looking to create a SharePoint workflow that copies an SPListItem from one list in an SPWeb to another list in another SPWeb. My question isn't how to copy, but more related to the workflow itself.

I want to prevent other workflows from being started on the SPListItem while in my copy workflow. I also need to prevent changes to the SPListItem while this is going on. Bascially, I don't want other people to change the SPListItem or issue new workflows on it while it is being copied to the destination SPList via my copy workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your workflow code to checkout the list item until the workflow ends and check it back in.